# Getting same output as cut() using speedier hist() or findInterval()?

Tags: r, histogram, cut

I read this article http://www.r-bloggers.com/comparing-hist-and-cut-r-functions/ and tested `hist()` to be faster than `cut()` by ~4 times on my PC. My script loops through cut() many times so the time-saving would be significant. I thus tried to switch to the speedier function but am having difficulties getting the exact output as per `cut()`.

From the sample code below:

```
data <- rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)  #generate data
my_breaks <- seq(-6, 6, by=1)  #create a vector that specifies my break points
cut(data, breaks=my_breaks)
```

I wish to get a vector comprising levels that each element of data is assigned to using my breakpoints, i.e. the exact output of `cut`:

```
 [1] (1,2]   (-1,0]  (0,1]   (1,2]   (0,1]   (-1,0]  (-1,0]  (0,1]   (-2,-1] (0,1]  
Levels: (-6,-5] (-5,-4] (-4,-3] (-3,-2] (-2,-1] (-1,0] (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,4] (4,5] (5,6]
>
```

**My question: How do I use elements of the `hist()` output (i.e. breaks, counts, density, mids, etc) or `findInterval` to reach my objective?**

Separately, I found an example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379128/r-switch-statement-on-comparisons using `findInterval`, but this requires me to create the interval labels beforehand, which is not what I want.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the premise. `hist` and `cut` do completely different things. `hist` counts the frequency in each bin and `cut` assigns to each value the corresponding bin. It's not surprising that the former is faster than the latter.

Comment: Voted to put on hold, as this question currently makes no sense at all.

Comment: Hi @Roland, in the R help for `cut()`, hist() is mentioned as being more efficient: _Instead of table(cut(x, br)), hist(x, br, plot = FALSE) is more efficient and less memory hungry_. So I thought: since they are mentioned 'under the same breath', can `hist()` truly serve as an alternative to `cut()` that could speed up my code.

Comment: The sentence you quoted says exactly this: `hist` is an alternative to `table(cut(...))`... not to `cut`.

Comment: yes, @plannapus, I do realise that, which is why I am seeing if anyone knows of a way to use it as an alternative. From my 3 months of working with R, my impression has often been that there are different ways to reach the same goal. So when I didn't succeed, my first thought was it's due to my limited knowledge in R.

Comment: There are alternatives (`findInterval` is one of them as you said) but `hist` isn't one since objects of class `histogram` contains exactly and at most the following components: breaks, counts, density, intensities, mids, xname and equidist (see `?hist` to know what they precisely are). None of them contain a vector of the same length as x with factors corresponding to the intervals.

Comment: @plannapus, noted on `hist()`. Have updated my title to include findInterval(). Seems like a gentleman has proposed a faster solution using findInterval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an implementation based on your `findInterval` suggestion which is 5-6 times faster than classical `cut`:

```
cut2 <- function(x, breaks) {
  labels <- paste0("(",  breaks[-length(breaks)], ",", breaks[-1L], "]")
  return(factor(labels[findInterval(x, breaks)], levels=labels))
}

library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
data <- rnorm(1e4, mean=0, sd=1)

microbenchmark(cut.default(data, my_breaks), cut2(data, my_breaks))

# Unit: microseconds
#                         expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
# cut.default(data, my_breaks) 3011.932 3031.1705 3046.5245 3075.3085 4119.147   100
#        cut2(data, my_breaks)  453.761  459.8045  464.0755  469.4605 1462.020   100

identical(cut(data, my_breaks), cut2(data, my_breaks))
# TRUE
```

Comment: Though, S3 method dispatch time only matters for shorter vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution, @sgibb, though your discussion with Roland is over my head. Let me hold out a bit more to see if there are other alternatives (I have already upvoted your solution).

Comment: @NoviceProg The issue they discussed was that originally `cut()` was compared with `cut2()` in the timings. `cut()` is an S3 method and hence the function, in this case, that is doing all the work is `cut.default()`. As such, when you time `cut()` you are timing `cut.default()` **and** the code that does S3 method dispatch. Timing just `cut.default()` would give a closer comparison as `cut2()` is not an S3 method. sgibb makes the point that S3 dispatch (the code that decides to call `cut.default()` when you used `cut()`) is negligible in terms of time for all but very short input data. HTH.

Comment: Resurrecting an old question :P It would be interesting to see how this solution scales with problem size, I tried with n = 1e8 and it's still a ~40% improvement but not 5-6 times faster...

Answer (score 4):

The `hist` function creates counts by bins in a similar way to a combination of `table` and `cut`.  For example,

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)

hist(x, plot = FALSE)
## $breaks
##  [1] -2.5 -2.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5
## 
## $counts
##  [1]  1  3  7 14 21 20 19  9  4  2

table(cut(x, seq.int(-2.5, 2.5, 0.5)))
## (-2.5,-2] (-2,-1.5] (-1.5,-1] (-1,-0.5]  (-0.5,0]   (0,0.5]   (0.5,1]
##         1         3         7        14        21        20        19
##   (1,1.5]   (1.5,2]   (2,2.5] 
##         9         4         2
```

If you want the raw output from `cut`, you can't use `hist`.

However, if the speed of `cut` is a problem (and you might want to double check that it really is the slow part of your analysis; see [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)), then you can use the lower level `.bincode`.  This ignores the input checking and label-creating functions of `cut`.

```
.bincode(x, seq.int(-2.5, 2.5, 0.5))
## [1]  4  6  4  9  6  4  6  7  7  5  9  6 ...
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. After implementing the much faster `cut` from sgibb, the improvement in speed is not as big as I hoped. Seems like the bottleneck is not `cut` afterall (sigh... back to the drawing board now...)

Comment: @NoviceProg You should profile your code. See `help("Rprof")`.

Comment: @Roland, thanks for your advice too! Will read up on `Rprof`. Thanks to everyone, I learnt a lot today!

Answer (score 1):

Why not skip the `factor()` step which is slow and memory intensive?

```
cut3 <- function(x, breaks) {
  out <- .bincode(x, breaks)
  labels <- paste0("(",  breaks[-length(breaks)], ",", breaks[-1L], "]")
  attr(out, "levels") <- labels
  class(out) <- "factor"
  out
}
```

Comparing to sgibb's `cut2`.

```
library(bench)

set.seed(1)
data <- rnorm(1e4, mean=0, sd=1)
my_breaks <- seq(-6, 6, by=1)
mark(cut.default(data, my_breaks), 
               cut2(data, my_breaks),
               cut3(data, my_breaks))
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression       min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory    
  <bch:expr>     <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>    
1 cut.default(d… 513µs  613µs     1490.   273.7KB     2.15   694     1      466ms <fct>  <Rprofmem>
2 cut2(data, my… 308µs  386µs     2396.   234.6KB     2.17  1104     1      461ms <fct>  <Rprofmem>
3 cut3(data, my… 188µs  200µs     4692.    39.1KB     2.17  2158     1      460ms <fct>  <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

#### Benchmark for bigger data

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(10^7)
mark(cut.default(x, my_breaks),
     cut2(x, my_breaks),
     cut3(x, my_breaks))
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression       min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory    
  <bch:expr>     <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>    
1 cut.default(x… 676ms  676ms      1.48     267MB     1.48     1     1      676ms <fct>  <Rprofmem>
2 cut2(x, my_br… 357ms  396ms      2.53   228.9MB     1.26     2     1      792ms <fct>  <Rprofmem>
3 cut3(x, my_br… 173ms  179ms      5.63    38.1MB     0        3     0      533ms <fct>  <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

As a side note, `cut.default()` can potentially be improved by just creating the factor directly from the bin codes as I've shown.