# Speed up slow dplyr code

Tags: r, benchmarking, dplyr

Using `cut` to convert a continuous variable to a factor with `dplyr` is very slow. With my real data (which has 400,000 rows and 96 variables), it takes 58 seconds.

My `data.frame` looks something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
diamonds <- rbind(diamonds, diamonds, diamonds, diamonds, diamonds, diamonds, diamonds, diamonds)
```

And my slow code is very similar to this:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(diamonds, price.bands = cut(price, c(326, 1000, 10000, 19000), labels = c("low", "mid", "high"), include.lowest=T))
```

Is there code I can use that would be faster?

Comment: I don't see much `dplyr` code here, and your battle neck is just `cut`. You could potentially use *assignment by reference* operator from `data.table` (`:=`) instead of `mutate` or you could try `findInterval` instead of `cut`, but you'll lose your labels.

Comment: Could it be that your data is grouped? That might increase the computation time. I don't see how `cut` would be _that_ slow otherwise. For example, to cut a vector of 1 million elements into three categories takes a quarter of a second on my laptop. What if you do `diamonds %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(price.bands = cut(price, c(326, 1000, 10000, 19000), labels = c("low", "mid", "high"), include.lowest=T))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting same output as cut() using speedier hist() or findInterval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775556/getting-same-output-as-cut-using-speedier-hist-or-findinterval)

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem slow on my computer:

```
> system.time({
+ x <- mutate(dia, price.bands = cut(price, c(326, 1000, 10000, 19000), labels = c("low", "mid", "high"), include.lowest=T))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.20    0.02    0.38 
> 
> str(x)
'data.frame':   431520 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ carat      : num  0.23 0.21 0.23 0.29 0.31 0.24 0.24 0.26 0.22 0.23 ...
 $ cut        : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "Fair"<"Good"<..: 5 4 2 4 2 3 3 3 1 3 ...
 $ color      : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "D"<"E"<"F"<"G"<..: 2 2 2 6 7 7 6 5 2 5 ...
 $ clarity    : Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "I1"<"SI2"<"SI1"<..: 2 3 5 4 2 6 7 3 4 5 ...
 $ depth      : num  61.5 59.8 56.9 62.4 63.3 62.8 62.3 61.9 65.1 59.4 ...
 $ table      : num  55 61 65 58 58 57 57 55 61 61 ...
 $ price      : int  326 326 327 334 335 336 336 337 337 338 ...
 $ x          : num  3.95 3.89 4.05 4.2 4.34 3.94 3.95 4.07 3.87 4 ...
 $ y          : num  3.98 3.84 4.07 4.23 4.35 3.96 3.98 4.11 3.78 4.05 ...
 $ z          : num  2.43 2.31 2.31 2.63 2.75 2.48 2.47 2.53 2.49 2.39 ...
 $ price.bands: Factor w/ 3 levels "low","mid","high": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>
```

Comment: Thanks Data Munger, but note this is a comment rather than an answer