# R getting break values from histogram

Tags: r, histogram

When you make a histogram and define the `breaks` argument, R uses some functions to generate those breaks. I want to obtain the range values for the breaks generated by the histogram such that if I made the following histogram

```
hist(df$foo, breaks = 5)
```

I want a list or data.frame that has the value ranges of the breaks:

```
list(c("1_lower"="<num>","1_upper"="<num2>","2_lower"="<num3>","2_upper"="<num4>"))
```

I hope this is possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the `cut`.  Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775556/getting-same-output-as-cut-using-speedier-hist-or-findinterval)

Comment: Look at the documentation `?hist` - if you set `h<-hist(...)`, then `h$breaks` will give you the breakpoints

Comment: `p <- hist(df$foo, breaks = 5); p$breaks`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Please post that as an answer so I can mark it. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation `?hist` - if you set `h<-hist(...)`, then `h$breaks` will give you the breakpoints.