# Switch statement is not working for numerical objects

Tags: r, switch-statement

I am new to R programming. I don't know whether we could use switch statements for numerical objects.

This is my code,

```
myfunction <- function() {
    x <- 10
    switch(x,
        1={
            print("one")
        },
        2={
            print("two")
        },
        3={
            print("three")
        },
        {
            print("default")     #Edited one..
        }
    )
}
```

I got this error,

```
test.R:4:18: unexpected '='
3:         switch(x,
4:                 1=
                    ^
```

Please help me out this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
                       switch(x,
                              print("one"),
                              print("two"),
                              print("three"))}

myfunction(1)
## [1] "one"
```

---

Edit:
As mentioned in comments, this method isn't evaluating the values that are being entered, rather uses them as an index. Thus, it works in your case but it won't work if the statements were to be reordered (see @Joshs answer for better approach).

Either way, I don't think `switch` is the right function to use in this case, because it is mainly meant for switching between different alternatives, while in your case, you are basically running the same function over and over. Thus, adding extra a statement for each alternative seems like too much work (if you, for example, wanted to display 20 different numbers, you'll have to write 20 different statements).

Instead, you could try the `english` package which will allow you to display as many numbers as you will define in the `ifelse` statement

```
library(english)
myfunction2 <- function(x) {
                 ifelse(x %in% 1:3, 
                        as.character(as.english(x)), 
                        "default")}
myfunction2(1)
## [1] "one"
myfunction2(4)
## [1] "default"
```

Alternatively, you could also avoid using `switch` (though not necessarily recommended) by using `match`

```
myfunction3 <- function(x) {
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = c("one", "two", "three"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
         ifelse(x %in% 1:3, 
          df$B[match(x, df$A)],
          "default")}
myfunction3(1)
## [1] "one"
myfunction3(4)
## [1] "default"
```

Comment: If you don't mind tell me how to add default for this switch statement?

Comment: Instead of `function(x)` do `function(x = 1)`, for example (if you want 1 to be your default). You can also remove all the names and just put `switch(x,
    {print("one")},
    {print("two")},
    {print("three")}
)` (wihtout the names) as MrFlick mentioned

Comment: I think I was not clear with my question. Sorry for that. I want to give default case for my switch case, how would I do that?

Comment: Exactly like I said... set to `function(x = 1)` and then try running `myfunction()`. Otherwise I don't understand you

Comment: I have edited the question, please see to it and give me a solution.

Comment: When you want `default` to be printed?

Comment: If the `x` has value other than 1, 2, 3 I want to print default.

Comment: From the examples on the `?switch` help page: "Numeric EXPR does not allow a default value to be specified." A NULL value is returned. You can test for a NULL return if you like, or you can force the character conversion. But i'm not sure this is the behavior you want anyway. See: `myfunction <- function(x) {switch(x,`3`=print("three"),`1`=print("one"),`2`=print("two"))}; myfunction(3)`

Comment: @MrFlick, I've edited the answer, though I don't see how *your* answer is any better.

Comment: I'm not saying my answer is any better. I just wanted to make it clear that the labels you had in your switch were meaningless with a numeric EXPR. Using the fancy back ticks doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MrFlick, Ok point taken, and I removed the backticks (i didn't want to copy paste your answer), but I already mentioned in [**my comments**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279543/switch-statement-is-not-working-for-numerical-objects/27279612?noredirect=1#comment43028349_27279612) that you can remove them like in your suggestion

Answer (score 10):

To take full advantage of `switch`'s functionality (in particular its ability to handle arbitrary values with a final "default" expression) **and** to handle numbers other than 1,2,3,...,  you'd be better off converting any input to a character string.

I would do something like this:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
    switch(as.character(x),
        "1" = print("one"),
        "2" = print("two"),
        "3" = print("three"),
        print("something other than 'one', 'two', or 'three'"))
}

myfunction(1)
# [1] "one"
myfunction(345)
# [1] "something other than 'one', 'two', or 'three'"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading the `?switch` help page. This seems fairly well described there. Names in R can never be numeric, ie c(1=5) is not allowed, nor is f(1=5, 2=5). If you really have 1,2 or 3, then you want just

```
switch(x,
    {print("one")},
    {print("two")},
    {print("three")}
)
```

(omit the names for numeric values)