# R - Using switch with logical values

Tags: r, switch-statement

`switch()` accepts as it's first argument

> "EXPR an expression evaluating to a number or a character string."

however, can it be coerced to working with a logical? If so, am I doing something else wrong in this code?

I have a column containing logical values in a data frame, and I want to write a new column containing values from the existing data in the data frame based on the logical parameters:

```
exampleCurrent <- data.frame(value = c(5.5, 4.5, 4, 2.9, 2),
                         off = as.logical(c("F", "F", "T", "T", "F")),
                         extremeValue = as.logical(c("F", "F", "F", "F", "T")),
                         eclMinWork = c(5, 5.3, 5, 4.7, 3),
                         eclMinOff = c(4, 3.2, 3, 4, 3))
```

I would like to get to this:

```
exampleWanted <- data.frame(value = c(5.5, 4.5, 4, 2.9, 2),
                        off = as.logical(c("F", "F", "T", "T", "F")),
                        extremeValue = as.logical(c("F", "F", "F", "F", "T")),
                        eclMinWork = c(5, 5.3, 5, 4.7, 4),
                        eclMinOff = c(4, 3.2, 3, 4, 3),
                        output = c(5, 4.5, 3, 2.9, 3))
```

The rules for selecting  a number are:

1. Check `off`. If `off` is FALSE, select from either `value` or `eclMinWork`. If `off` is TRUE, select from either `value` or `eclMinOff`
2. Check `extremeValue`. If `extreneValue` = FALSE, select the smaller of `value` and the field in step 1. If `extremeValue` = TRUE, select the value from the field in step 1.

I have successfully written an `ifelse()` that performs, though I am wondering if I can use `switch` instead.

```
exampleGenerated <- cbind(exampleCurrent, bestCase =
                          switch(exampleCurrent$off,
                                 FALSE = ifelse(exampleCurrent$value<exampleCurrent$eclMinWork,exampleCurrent$value, exampleCurrent$eclMinWork),
                                 TRUE = ifelse(exampleCurrent$value<exampleCurrent$eclMinOff,exampleCurrent$value, exampleCurrent$eclMinOff)))
```

The above throws an error, I am assuming as FALSE is not a character, and is not (on the face of it) a numeric or character:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in: switch(exampleCurrent$off, FALSE ="
```

However, my attempts at wrapping `as.numeric` and `as.character` around the variables have also failed. Is there a way to do it, or am I missing a fundamental mistake in my code?

Comment: I don't think that even if you will convert it to character, you will be able to pass an `ifelse` statement within `switch`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that may be true, though if I replace the `ifelse()` with a straight numerical value, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27280129/3001626)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, if I understand correctly, you're suggesting to use as.character around `off`, and then "" on false and true. Afraid I still haven't succeeded: `exampleGenerated <- cbind(exampleCurrent, bestCase =
                              switch(as.character(exampleCurrent$off),
                                     "FALSE" = "A",
                                     "TRUE" = "B"))`

Comment: That's because `switch` can't accept a vector longer than 1 (try reading the error message). In order for your example to work, you''ll have to loop it, i.e., `sapply(exampleCurrent$off, function(x) switch(as.character(x), "FALSE" = "A", "TRUE" = "B"))`. But I'd just go with @Svens nice solution.

Comment: Btw, for your specific example, you could just do a simple indexing such as `LETTERS[1:2][exampleCurrent$off + 1]`

Comment: There's no reason to use a multi-branch tool like `switch` when you've only got two possible states. Stick with `if` and its friend `ifelse` .  Unless, I suppose, you are investigating quintenary logic :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `switch` for this task. It is easier with `ifelse` and `pmin`:

```
tmp <- with(exampleCurrent, ifelse(off, eclMinOff, eclMinWork))
transform(exampleCurrent, 
          bestCase = ifelse(extremeValue, tmp, pmin(value, tmp)))

#   value   off extremeValue eclMinWork eclMinOff bestCase
# 1   5.5 FALSE        FALSE        5.0       4.0      5.0
# 2   4.5 FALSE        FALSE        5.3       3.2      4.5
# 3   4.0  TRUE        FALSE        5.0       3.0      3.0
# 4   2.9  TRUE        FALSE        4.7       4.0      2.9
# 5   2.0 FALSE         TRUE        3.0       3.0      3.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean I *can't* use switch(), or just that I shouldn't?

Comment: @DaveRGP `switch` isn't vectorized, so you can't use it for this task.